# Having a div with buttons over a video

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, video

I have a video in my page and I would like to have a div with specific controls over the video instead of the regular ones.

I have tried setting the div to absolute but even though the buttons appear, they are not clickable.

Is there any way (without jquery) to do this where the buttons in the div are above the video and clickable?

Video:

```
<div id="divVideo" style="text-align:center"> 
<video id="video1" width="720" autoplay loop>
<source src="01_vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
```

Buttons (they have a small script):

```
<button type="button" onclick="playPause(this)" class="btn btn-primary">&#9646;&#9646</button>
<button type="button" onclick="muteUnmute(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Mute</button>
<button type="button" onclick="goHD(this)" class="btn btn-primary">HD</button>
```

Script (probably unnecessary):

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause(btn) { 
if (myVideo.paused) {
    myVideo.play(); 
    btn.innerHTML = "&#9646;&#9646"
} else {
    myVideo.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "&#9658"
}
} 

function muteUnmute(etc) { 
if (myVideo.muted) {
    myVideo.muted = false
    etc.innerHTML = "Mute"
}   else {
    myVideo.muted = true; 
    etc.innerHTML = "Unmute"
} 
}

function goHD(el)   {
if (myVideo.width != 1280){
    myVideo.width = 1280
    el.innerHTML = "SD"
    }
else{
    myVideo.width = 720
    el.innerHTML = "HD";
}
}
```

This is my CSS:

```
#botoes {
float: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0; z-index: 1; 
width: 100%; 
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#divVideo {
position: relative;
width: 720px;
float: left;
height: 405px;
}
#video {
position: relative;
width: 720px;
height: 405px;
background-color: blue;
float: left;
display: block;
}
```

How do I make the buttons float over the video (that is inside a div)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot add a realistic video here. So imagine the image to be a video.

```css
.video {position: relative; width: 350px;}
.video img {display: block;}
.video .buttons {position: absolute; bottom: 0; z-index: 1; width: 100%; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="playPause(this)" class="btn btn-primary">&#9646;&#9646</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="muteUnmute(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Mute</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="goHD(this)" class="btn btn-primary">HD</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you wanna make it only appear once you hover your mouse over the video, there you go:

```css
.video {position: relative; width: 350px;}
.video img {display: block;}
.video .buttons {position: absolute; bottom: 0; z-index: 1; width: 100%; text-align: center; display: none;}
.video:hover .buttons {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="playPause(this)" class="btn btn-primary">&#9646;&#9646</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="muteUnmute(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Mute</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="goHD(this)" class="btn btn-primary">HD</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: DAMN, gonna put it in my code :D You sir are golden. Thanks!

Comment: And thank you for letting me know of this awesome website placehold.it

Comment: @AndréSá Can you create a JSFiddle or add a snippet that works??

Comment: I think this is correct: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=lt8Nmpohmp (never needed to use jsfiddle before)

Comment: Nopes. You need to save it and then get the URL to me.

Comment: @AndréSá Perfect buddy.

Comment: @AndréSá You haven't added my CSS. Will update the fiddle and let you know.

Comment: I was away but I am looking at it right now. Is it still possible to do add the hover with this code? Thanks.

Comment: oops, some divs fell out of place. I think I can arrange that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
video {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
div {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" controls="" preload="none" mediagroup="myVideoGroup" poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
  <source id="mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source id="webm" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source id="ogv" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
<div>
  <button>Start</button>
  <button>End</button>
</div>
```